# Progress Bar and Background Worker

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I have a progress bar and backgroundworker in VB.Net that I would want to work in a different form as given below:

```
Form1()
{
MaxRows = 10
for i = 0 to MaxRows then
// Update my value on the progressbar
....

next
}
```

**ProgressBarForm**

```
Private Sub ProgressBarForm_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        TransferProgressBar.Visible = True
        ProgressBarBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ProgressBarBackgroundWorker_DoWork(sender As Object, e As ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles ProgressBarBackgroundWorker.DoWork
        For i = 0 To TransferProgressBar.Maximum
            'Dim Percentage As Integer = Math.Round(((i / (TransferProgressBar.Maximum - TransferProgressBar.Minimum)) * 100))
            ProgressBarBackgroundWorker.ReportProgress(i / 100)
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub ProgressBarBackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles ProgressBarBackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged
        TransferProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
        PercentageLabel.Text = "Processing....." & TransferProgressBar.Value.ToString() & "%"
    End Sub

    Private Sub ProgressBarBackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles ProgressBarBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted
        MsgBox("Task Completed!")
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
```

How can I update my progressbar value using the backgroundworker from another form/Sub? Kindly let me know. I'm getting a bit confused here.

Comment: You can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345155/vb-net-updating-progress-bar-from-background-worker?rq=1) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533412/multithreading-for-a-progressbar-and-code-locations-vb-net).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You seem to have it back to front.  Rather than the `BackgroundWorker` handling the `ProgressBar` updates, use the BGW to do the time consuming work.  Then at intervals you can provide updates for the ProgressBar/Form using the built-in `ReportProgress` method.

Normally, you cannot (directly) access UI controls, like a `ProgressBar`, from a thread other than the one it was created on (ie the UI thread).  The `ReportProgress` event is raised on the original/UI thread to make basic progress reporting easy.

However, it is pretty much limited to only that. To do more, for instance post results of the long process to a `ListBox`, you would use a Delegate to update the control on the other/UI thread.

#### The Form with the long running task

```
Private WithEvents bgw As New BackgroundWorker
Private frmProg As ProgForm          ' progress bar form

' start up
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender ...etc
    ' set up 
    bgw.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    bgw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True

    If frmProg Is Nothing Then          ' make sure progress form is instanced
        ProgForm = New frmProg
    End If
        
    If bgw.IsBusy = False Then
        frmProg.Show()
        bgw.RunWorkerAsync(10)         ' do some important work x10
    End If

End Sub

' the job that will take a while
Private Sub bgw_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) 
                  Handles bgw.DoWork
    ' ToDo: with multiple workers use sender, not 'bgw'
    ' get the amount of work to do
    Dim numToDo As Integer = CInt(e.Argument)

    ' important, time consuming work done here
    For n As Integer = 1 To numToDo
        ' do the "work"
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)

        ' post a notice, passing the percentage (raises the ProgressChanged event)
        bgw.ReportProgress(Convert.ToInt32((n / numToDo) * 100)  
    Next
End Sub

' event raised from DoWork via ReportProgress
Private Sub bgw_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) 
      Handles bgw.ProgressChanged
    ' method added on the Progress form to 

    ' receive percentage and update the meter:
    frmProg.UpdateProgress(e.ProgressPercentage)

    ' if the progress bar was on the same form,
    ' update it directly:
    'MyProgBar.Value = MyProgBar.Maximum
    'MyProgBar.Value = pct
End Sub

' optional event raised when the long running task is complete
Private Sub bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, 
         e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bgw.RunWorkerCompleted

    ' when all done, report that too
    MessageBox.Show("Work Complete!")
End Sub
```

Note that normally using `Thread.Sleep` freezes the UI.  That doesnt happen here because it is the `BackgroundWorker` not the UI thread which is put to sleep.

#### The Form with the progress bar:

```
Public Sub UpdateProgress(pct As Integer)

   ' ToDo: Add error checking 
    progress.Value = progress.Maximum
    progress.Value = pct
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Imports System.Threading

Class MainWindow

    Private myBackgroundWorker As BackgroundWorker
    Sub New()

        myBackgroundWorker = New BackgroundWorker With {
            .WorkerReportsProgress = True,
            .WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
        }
        AddHandler myBackgroundWorker.DoWork, AddressOf DoWork
        AddHandler myBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf RunWorkerCompleted
        AddHandler myBackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged, AddressOf ProgressChanged

    End Sub
    Dim maximo = 1000
    Dim count = 0
    Private Sub DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)
        Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = TryCast(sender, BackgroundWorker)
        While count < maximo
            Thread.Sleep(1)
            worker.ReportProgress(count, "")
            count += 1
        End While
    End Sub
    Private Sub RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
        radiobuton.IsEnabled = True
        labelprogres.Content = "100%"
    End Sub

    Private Sub ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs)
        progres.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
        labelprogres.Content = count / maximo * 100 & "%"
    End Sub
    Private Sub RadButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles radiobuton.Click
        If Not myBackgroundWorker.IsBusy Then
            myBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
            radiobuton.IsEnabled = False
            progres.Maximum = maximo
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).