# Update control on main form via Background Worker with method in another class VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, class, thread-safety, backgroundworker

I have been banging my head against the wall all day trying to figure this one out.

I am finishing up a program to simply delete files in specific temp folders. I have read that it is sometimes good practice to create separate classes for methods and variables. So I have created a separate class for a couple methods to delete files and folders in a specified directory. I am using a Background Worker in my **Form1** class and am calling my **deleteFiles()** method from my **WebFixProcesses** class in the **DoWork** event in the **Form1** class. I am using a Background Worker so that I can easily report progress back to a progress bar on my main form.

**The files get deleted without an issue but I just can't get the label on my main form to reflect the current file being deleted. the label doesn't change in any way.**
 I know the formula is correct as I can get this working if the method is in the **Form1** class. and I simply use:

```
 Invoke(Sub()
     lblStatus.Text = File.ToString
     lblStatus.Refresh()
 End Sub)
```

here is my method that I am calling from the **WebFixProcesses** class:

```
Public Shared Sub deleteFiles(ByVal fileLocation As String)
    For Each file As String In Directory.GetFiles(fileLocation)
        Try

            fileDisplay.Add(file)
            For i = 1 To fileDisplay.Count
                file = fileDisplay(i)
                Form1.BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(CInt(i / fileDisplay.Count) * 100)

            Next
            IO.File.Delete(file)                
            Form1.labelText(file)
            Form1.labelRefresh()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    Next
End Sub
```

**labelText()** and **labelRefresh()** are methods from my main form which are using delegates to try to pass information to the control:

```
Public Sub labelText(ByVal file As String)
    If lblStatus.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim del As New txtBoxDelegate(AddressOf labelText)
        Me.Invoke(del, file)
    Else
                   lblStatus.Text = file.ToString()
    End If

End Sub
Public Sub labelRefresh()
    If lblStatus.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim del As New txtBoxRefDelegate(AddressOf labelRefresh)
        Me.Invoke(del)
    Else
                   lblStatus.Refresh()

    End If
End Sub
```

If anyone can help me out to inform me what I may be doing wrong it would be immensely appreciated as my head is in a lot of pain from this. And maybe I am going at it all wrong, and just being stubborn keeping my methods in their own class. But any help would be awesome. Thanks guys!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Progress Bar and Background Worker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27565851/progress-bar-and-background-worker)

Comment: Standard VB.NET problem, we get them at a rate of about 2 a week.  Always different code, always the same problem.  Form1.labelText(file) is a bug, calling the labelText() method requires an *object reference*.  But Form1 is not an object, it is a type.  That this is still possible in VB.NET is a horrid compatibility hack.  But it doesn't work when you use it in a worker thread, you get a *new* Form1 object.  You can't see it and it is not the one you are looking at.  You need a proper reference.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Guys. Hans can u clarify your above comment in that you are stating that this is a bug with vb.net and I need to reference my Form1 class in a different way? If so, what would be the proper way to reference? I belive I have tried referencing with: Form1 mainForm As New Form1... still with no luck

Comment: Also tried: Form1 mainForm As Form1 with no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Hans wrote on the question comment is true: `Form1` is a **type**, not an **instance**, but to make things easier to newbye programmes (coming from VB6), M$ did a "mix", allowing you to use the form name as the instance of the form in the main thread.

This however works only if you are on *that* thread.

If you reference `Form1` from *another* thread, a new instance of `Form1` is created.

To solve the issue, add this code to the form:

```
Private Shared _instance As Form1
Public ReadOnly Property Instance As Form1
    Get
        Return _instance
    End Get
End Property
```

We will use this property to store the current instance of the form. To do so, add this line to the `Load` event:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    _instance = Me

    'other code here
End Sub
```

Now, from every class, in any thread, if you use

```
Form1.Instance
```

...you get the actual form. Now you can `Invoke`, even from the same form:

```
    Me.instance.Invoke(Sub()
                           Me.lblStatus.Text = "Hello World"
                       End Sub)
```

Comment: Hey John that worked!!! bahhh thank you so much for that!! it will save me so much time in the future. I had read similar solutions but none as straight forward so that I understood exactly what was happening. Thanks again! I would vote up but my rep is still too low.