# Use a progress bar to track loop progress without affecting loop speed VB

Tags: vb.net

I can get a progress bar to increment inside the Do loop but it massively affects the speed of the loop. How can i keep track of progress of the Do Until loop without affecting it?

```
Do Until temp = pbTemp2
temp+= 1
progressbar1.increment(1) '<--- i dont want this in here but still need to track the progress
loop
```

Comment: Run the loop in a background thread and have it increment a variable instead. Then place a timer on your form/control and have it continuously update the progress bar based on the variable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27565851/progress-bar-and-background-worker

Comment: You could increment every x time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The middle ground between what Visual Vincent proposed and a BackgroudWorker.
(I'm assuming this is related to .NET `WinForms`).

Crate a Thread to perform some work, and use a [SynchronizationContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Threading.SynchronizationContext);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework) to queue the results the process to the UI context.

The `SynchronizationContext` will then dispatch an asynchronous message to the synchronization context through a [SendOrPostCallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.sendorpostcallback(v=vs.110).aspx) delegate, a method that will perform its elaboration in that context. The UI thread in this case.

The asynchronous message is sent using [SynchronizationContext.Post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.post(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

The UI thread will not freeze and can be used to perform other tasks in the meanwhile.

How this works:
- Define a method which will interact with some UI control:
**`SyncCallback = New SendOrPostCallback(AddressOf Me.UpdateProgress)`**
- Initialize a new Thread, specifying the worker method that the thread will use. 
**`Dim pThread As New Thread(AddressOf Progress)`**
- Starting the thread, it's possible to pass a parameter to the worker method, in this case is the maximum value of a progress bar.
**`pThread.Start(MaxValue)`**
- When the worker method needs to report back its progress to the (UI) context, this is done using the asychronous `Post()` method of the `SynchronizationContext`.
**`SyncContext.Post(SyncCallback, temp)`**

> Here, the thread is started using a `Button.Click` event, but it could
>   be anything else.

```
Imports System.Threading

Private SyncContext As SynchronizationContext
Private SyncCallback As SendOrPostCallback

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button11.Click
    SyncContext = WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Current
    SyncCallback = New SendOrPostCallback(AddressOf Me.UpdateProgress)
    Dim MaxValue As Integer = ProgressBar1.Maximum

    Dim pThread As New Thread(AddressOf Progress)
    pThread.IsBackground = True
    pThread.Start(MaxValue)
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateProgress(state As Object)
    ProgressBar1.Value = CInt(state)
End Sub

Private Sub Progress(parameter As Object)
    Dim temp As Integer = 0
    Dim MaxValue As Integer = CType(parameter, Integer)
    Do
        temp += 1
        SyncContext.Post(SyncCallback, temp)
    Loop While temp < MaxValue
End Sub
```