# How to handle long running tasks in VB.NET forms?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms

I am currently working on a VB.NET form that automatically create Word documents according to an Excel file and a few extra data asked by the form (Project Name, Customer Name, Use SQL, ...).

This procedure works fine and takes approximatelly 1 or 2 minutes to complete.
The issue is that all my script is in `ButtonGenerate.Click` Handler. So when the Generate button is pressed the form window is bricked and it's impossible to Cancel...

It shouldn't be in a Click handler. Opening a new thread for that long task seems better. But Multithreading isn't very familiar to me.
I tryed launching the script with

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(...
```

but my Generate Sub sets labels and update a Progress Bar in the main form, so I doesn't work unless I use

```
Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub()
    label.Text = "..."
    ProgressBar.Value = 10
    ' ...
End Sub)
```

each time I need to update something on the form and I can't even retrieve any new push of a button with that (A cancel button would be nice).

This is basically my code :

```
Public Class TestFichesAutomation

Private Sub BtnGenerate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnGenerate.Click
    System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Sub() Generate())
End Sub

Public Sub Generate()
    ' Check user options, retrieve Excel Data, SQL, Fill in custom classes, create Word docs (~ 1 minute)
End Sub
```

So How would you handle that script ? Is Threading even a good solution ?

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27565851/progress-bar-and-background-worker

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Progress Bar and Background Worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27565851/progress-bar-and-background-worker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into using the [Async/Await structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/async/)

if the work you need to do is CPU bound, i like using `Task.Run()` doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.8)

By making your event handler Async and having it `Await` the work, you prevent the UI from locking up <s>and avoid the use of `Invoke` in most cases.</s>

ex:

```
Private Async Sub Btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn.Click
    Dim Result As Object = Await Task.Run(Function() SomeFunction())
    'after the task returned by Task.Run is completed, the sub will continue, thus allowing you to update the UI etc..

End Sub
```

For progress reporting with `Async/Await` you might be interested in [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/)

Comment: Although I would generally favor `async` and `await`, since the question wants to update the UI, you can't just hand-wave away the `Invoke` as long as the work is being done on another thread as with `Task.Run`---and I'd guess this is sufficiently CPU-bound to be worth doing so.

Comment: i'd say there's ways around it, but you might be right that it's easier to just use `invoke`. However since you need `invoke` in either case (`Async/Await`or more directly using the threadpool), i'd still go for `Async/Await`as imo it leads to cleaner code.

Comment: I definitely prefer `Async/Await`, I didn't mean to suggest otherwise.

Comment: Then i misunderstood you, re-reading your comment i can indeed see that's not what you said.

Comment: No worries, I might have been a little too terse and so a little got lost.  I was trying to say that while there are many benefits to using `Async` and `Await`, they don't get you out of needing to use `Invoke` to update the UI from code running on a non-UI thread.  Really, I'd say they're somewhat orthogonal.  You very well might `Await` something spun up using `Task.Run()`, and also need to use `Invoke` from the spun up code in some form or fashion to get a UI update.

Comment: Agreed, separate from the `Async/Await`matter : I think you can prevent the use of `invoke` if you use an atomic operation to increment a progress variable like `PercentComplete`, assuming you calculate the total work needed in advance. The UI Thread could then check it periodically and update the progressbar.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot for your help ^^ and for the useful doc.

My app now open a new thread and uses 2 custom classes to act like buffers :

```
Private Async Sub Btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn.Click
     myProgress = New Progress
    ' a custom class just for the UI with the current task, current SQL connection status and progress value in %

    _Options.ProjectName = TextBoxProjectName.Text
    _Options.CustomerName = TextBoxCustomerName.Text
    ...
    ' Fill in a custom "_Options" private class to act as a buffer between the 2 thread (the user choices)       

    Loading = New Loading()
    Me.Visible = False
    Loading.Show() ' Show the Loading window (a ProgressBar and a label : inputLine)

    Task.Run(Function() Generate(Progress, _Options))
    Me.Visible = True
End Sub


Public Async Function Generate(ByVal myProgress As Progress, ByVal Options As Options) As Task(Of Boolean)
    ' DO THE LONG JOB and sometimes update the UI :
    myProgress.LoadingValue = 50 ' %
    myProgress.CurrentTask= "SQL query : " & ...
    Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub() UpdateLoading()))
    ' Check if the task has been cancelled ("Cancelled" is changed by a passvalue from the Loading window):
    If myProgress.Cancelled = True Then ...
    ' Continue ...
End Function


Public Shared Sub UpdateLoading()
    MyForm.Loading.ProgressBar.Value = myProgress.LoadingValue
    MyForm.Loading.inputLine.Text = myProgress.CurrentTask
    ' ...
End Sub
```