# How can I write my application as a multithreaded application in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a C# Windows application that does many tasks. some of these tasks are very time wasting. When I run these type of tasks, the other parts of my application will be disabled.

How can I write my application to avoid this? Is using threads a good solution? Is it safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've had the background worker suggested. The other way is to start a new thread yourself.

```
void main()
{
   Thread worker = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoStuff));
   worker.Start();
}

private void DoStuff() 
{
  // long running work in here
}
```

You can also use the [ParameterizedThreadStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx)  if you want to throw in arguments to your DoStuff() method.

Answer (score 3):

A first thing you could try is using the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

**Example**

You might have this method that takes a lot of time to run: `void HeavyLifting()`

So to delegate some work use a `BackgroundWorker`!

```
var worker = new BackgroundWorker();

worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(someHeavyWork);
```

The event method someHeavyWork just calls HeavyLifting in this case.

To start the worker simply do this:

`worker.RunWorkAsync();`

**Tip: Updating the GUI Thread**

Remember that if you are going to change things in the GUI-thread through this thread, you need to use invoke/delegates for that. You can read about this on MSDN: [How can I update my user interface from a thread that did not create it?](http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/17/91685.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

A very [nice online resource](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) for understanding threading in .NET with lots of samples; shared by Joseph Albahari.

Comment: I second this - Albahari's paper is an excellent place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you can use the [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx) to queue background tasks in programs that aren't Windows Forms Applications. In .NET 4.0, there are a lot of new features for parallel programming (like Parallel LINQ, ...). [Patterns for Parallel Programming: Understanding and Applying Parallel Patterns with the .NET Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=86b3d32b-ad26-4bb8-a3ae-c1637026c3ee&displaylang=en) might be interesting for you.

Cheers
Matthias

Answer (score 1):

Or if you use .net 4.0 you can use the task framework, it is nice. But be carefull not writting to the UI controls from another thread.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned use the BackgroundWorker and take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952201/display-progress-bar-while-doing-some-work-in-c/1969933#1969933) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902384/make-a-backgroundworker-do-several-operations-sequentially-without-freezing-the-f/1907501#1907501).

Answer (score -1):

Try using [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

Create a BackGroundWorker (available at the toolbox)

Create the DoWork event (you can access this one in the event tab of the BGW properties)

```
    private void BGWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        DoTimeConsumingTask();
    }
```

and call it with the following:

```
BGWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

You can pass a variable to the DoWork handler, which could be accessed throug

```
e.Argument //(It comes as an Object, you can use int.Parse, .ToString() or whatever
```